# solr: multivalued dateranges (representing opening hours)

Tags: architecture, lucene, solr

Consider a bar which might have multiple openinghours, depending on the day of week (+ some special days when it might be closed)

I want to be able to lookup all bars that are currently open and that will be open for the next, say, 3 hours. (or be able to ask: 'open on 18-10-2011 from 7 until (at least) 10 )

The best thing I believe would be to have a 'open,close'-tuple for each date (other suggestions welcome)

Without, as far as I know ?, a fieldtype that combines open/close hours in 1 field, I can naively (but wrongly) define this structure using 2 fields: 'open' and 'closed', which need to be multivalued.

Now index them like:

```
open: 2011-11-08:1800 - close: 2011-11-09:0300
open: 2011-11-09:1700 - close: 2011-11-10:0500
open: 2011-11-10:1700 - close: 2011-11-11:0300
```

And queries would be of the form:

```
open < now && close > now+3h
```

But since there is no way to indicate that 'open' and 'close' are pairwise related I will get a lot of false positives, e.g the above document would be returned for:

```
open < 2011-11-09:0100 && close > 2011-11-09:0600
```

because SOME opendate is before  `2011-11-09:0100` (i.e: `2011-11-08:1800`) and SOME closedate is after `2011-11-09:0600` (for example: `2011-11-11:0300`)  but these open and close-dates are not pairwise related.

I have been thinking about a totally different approach using Solr dynamic fields, in which each and every opening and closing-date gets it's own dynamic field, e.g:

- _date_2011-11-09_open: 1800
- _date_2011-11-09_close: 0300
- _date_2011-11-09_open: 1700
- _date_2011-11-10_close: 0500
- _date_2011-11-10_open: 1700
- _date_2011-11-11_close: 0300

Then, the client should know the date to query, and thus the correct fields to query. This would solve the problem, since startdate/ enddate are nor pairwise -related, but I fear this can be a big issue from a performance standpoint (especially memory consumption of the Lucene fieldcache)

Thusfar, I haven't found a satisfactory solution. 
Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While keeping granularity on Bars like I want (instead of BarsxDate) it's possible to use the expirimental Lucene Spatial Playground implementation.

The use-case + general solution is here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2155?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=comment-13115244#comment-13115244

Comment: Any chance you could give some details on how you implemented this? From what I'm reading, LSP doesn't support multivalued fields...

Comment: I haven't actually implemented it (yet) and it's been a while since I thought about it. Have you read the comments in which David Smiley responds to this use case? (I noticed the above hotlink to the correct comment didn't work) . This one does. Hth: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2155?focusedCommentId=13114839&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13114839

Comment: Yes, I read that comment, but it seems like he's not talking about supporting multivalued date ranges. It seems like I found a post where this was explicitly said, but I can't seem to find it now, though I may have gotten it confused with the FieldMaskingSpanQuery suggestion (which itself seems like it's going away, see: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/jira-Created-LUCENE-3723-Remove-FieldMaskingSpanQuery-or-fix-its-scoring-td3687698.html)

Comment: Perhaps I was thinking of his comment "If your query is a time duration and you want it to reside completely within an indexed time duration, then no-can-do for now."

Comment: David comes with an okay alternative (at least for me) right after: "Based on the nature of your use-case, it may suffice to use multiple spatial filter queries, each one a point (time) at each hour interval of the desired query duration." So, if you want to have restaurants open [now, Now + 3h], you'd need to query all documents which have the 4 points representing [now, now+1, now+2, now+3]... that's how I read his first approach.. He likes the second approach better, but I'm not grokking it at the moment :).. hth some

Comment: of course this theoretically allows gaps of of restaurant being closed between the interval of an hour, although in real-life that seems unlikely. If not granular enough, take 30min as interval

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20706/discussion-between-gabriel-and-geert-jan)

Comment: FYI: I raised the question again on Solr User List: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Modeling-openinghours-using-multipoints-td4025336.html. In short: doable with Solr 4 out-of-the-box!

Comment: Nice write up: https://people.apache.org/~hossman/spatial-for-non-spatial-meetup-20130117/

Answer (score 0):

First a question - do you really have open times for dates?  not days of the week?  but leaving that aside (it doesn't change the answer in any important way), what you should do is create a document for every bar/date combination.  In each of these documents you will need all the fields you are planning to search on; maybe that includes location, bar name, etc.  So those fields will be denormalized (duplicated across many related documents).

That way you can do the query you describe and get precise results.

Comment: 'do you really have open times for dates?'. I figured this is the best way to incorporate special dates, which often have different openinghours from their 'weekday counterpart'.  As to your solution, I have thought of that (it's often the first thing on our mind, when thinking Lucene / Nosql : denormalize! :), but before going that route I would like to know if there aren't any less intrusive methods.

Comment: A doc per BarXdate would, besides needing indexing and search changing on our client, blow up memory because the lucene fieldcache for all sorted fields

Comment: Ignore the previous comment please. Say we have 100 dates. This would mean the nr of BarXdate-docs would be 100*#bars. This just feels very wasteful, because of the relatively minor functional need.  Moreover, now querying ALWAYS needs to include a specific date, otherwise duplicate bars are returned (i.e: the same bar with different dates) . Lastly, we have numerous other fields where we sort on. Going this route would enlarge the memory footprint needed bigtime, because the Lucene fieldcache of each of these sorted fields grows by a factor 100. Just to much for the small funct-gain.

Comment: of course, thanks for your thoughts, but I'll go a different route. Perhaps defining a custom fieldtype 'daterange' with 'from' and 'to' being both dates (if that is possible). A multivalued field of 'dateranges' would then solve the problem.