# Solr: Modeling opening hours in schema.xml

Tags: search, solr, solr4

I'm currently try to use solr to query for open restaurants. These restaurants have opening hours which are represented by 30min time slots. So e.g. 10:00 - 10:30, 10:30 - 11:00, ... These time slots can be different for each day.

I've seen that a nearly similar problem was discussed in [solr: multivalued dateranges (representing opening hours)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548439/solr-multivalued-dateranges-representing-opening-hours) , but without providing a proper solution.

Beside the opening hours I have a lot of other data in my index for facet searches and so on. So I cannot duplicate the restaurant data for each start and end time.

What would be the best approach to model this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read [this](https://people.apache.org/~hossman/spatial-for-non-spatial-meetup-20130117/). It is an approach to use SOLRs spatial capabilities for modeling time spans.

Here is a short roundup of that approach:

You define a rectangular (instead of spherical) "world", where both axes have "time" as their unit. A time span (opening time) is then modeled as a single point (starttime, endtime) in that world. You can then use spatial polygon queries to query the time spans.